# Visual studio code java compile not work with UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, visual-studio-code

I am having a bug with the [java debug plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug) in my VS Code on Windows 10. When I try to print some special characters with this code :

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "こんにちは世界!";
        System.out.println(hello);
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(oStream, "UTF-8"));
        try {
            out.write(hello);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I set the file encode is UTF-8 , when I debug my code in Vs Code, the debug console and the file show broken characters, if I change file encode to UTF-8 with BOM both debug console and the file show correct characters. But changing file encode to UTF-8 is not a solution because [java does not support UTF-8 encoding does not recognize initial BOM](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058) . So changing file encode to UTF-8 with BOM break my project, because every time i compile my code with javac or build tools like gradle, maven ..., it will throw this error :

```
> gradle build

> Task :compileJava FAILED
D:\Workspace\Code\~SourceCode\Java\TestEncode\src\main\java\App.java:1: error: illegal character: '\ufeff'
?import java.io.BufferedWriter;
^
```

(I don't know what magic M$ use to make UTF-8 with BOM work heare!)

Does anybody know a fix or workaround for this?

Comment: Well, don't use a BOM, make sure your file is encoded in UTF8 without BOM, and make sure you've configured the Java compiler used by gradle to use UTF8 to parse the Java files. Googling for "gradle compiler UTF8" should give you the answer.

Comment: I have no problem with gradle + UTF8 without BOM. The problem is if I use UTF8 without BOM, vscode java debug will compile special characters in my java file to broken characters, and I can not use UTF8 with BOM because it will break my gradle build task.

I'm thinking of running gradle build before every time i run java debug and config my debugger to use the class file generated by gradle task, but I don't know how.

Comment: There is always the choice of not using non-ASCII in the source file, e.g. change `"こんにちは世界!"` to `"\u3053\u3093\u306B\u3061\u306F\u4E16\u754C!"`. Not ideal, but it'll fix the problem. --- Or you could use a Java IDE.

Comment: my current workaround is disable auto compile feature of vscode java debug, add a pre launch task in lauch.json to call gradle build task before i start debug, and write a task in gradle.build to copy all .class file compiled by gradle to bin folder (by default, vscode java debug will compile and run .class file in bin folder)